# Language selection not working Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, language

My clients Chrome browser is displaying results in French rather than English (UK). I have performed the → Settings → Show Advanced Settings → Language → English.

When I select English, Chrome Browser informs me this language cannot be used or be used for spell checking.

An example is when I open google.co.uk the top of the screen rather than the usual "you" the french word for "you" is displayed "vous"

I have even removed the French language selection from the menu. Still displaying French. I have also checked the language settings of Windows and that is English

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to configuration and disable synchronization, then close Chrome.
2. Search for the google chrome settings file. Mac: User>Library>Application Support>Google>Chrome>Default
3. Search for a file caller "Preferences" and open it with a text editor.
4. Search for "lan" and find language, next to it you will find all the installed languages, leave only the ones you need and leave the default as first one, then save.
5. Open up Google Chrome and go back to your sync settings,then go to the managed syncronized data in google control panel (https://chrome.google.com/sync?hl=es-419)
6. Go down and click on the reset synchronization button, it will log you out of your chrome profile/account
7. Go back and relog into you Chrome profile/Google account, reenable sync and sync all data.

That should do it, worked for me.

Comment: Open up Google Chrome and go back to your sync settings,then go to the managed syncronized data in google control panel https://chrome.google.com/sync THIS WORKS! Nothing else does.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select one of the specific English options e.g. ("English (United Kingdom)" or "English (United States)"). If you choose one of the specific options, you should see something like the below:

[image: Chrome Language Settings 1]

Just for clarification, this is what the "English" options looks like on my Chrome browser:

[image: Chrome Language Settings 2]

---

If everything above doesn't apply, your Google search language setting may be set to show results in French:

[Search Settings](https://www.google.co.uk/preferences?hl=en-GB&fg=1#languages)

[image: Google Search Settings]

---

Finally, if all else fails, try clearing your browser cache and cookie data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I have tried this and still no joy. I even tried selecting the UK one and then when that did not work I tried the US selection but alas both failed to change the language from French to English...

Comment: Have you checked the Google search language settings? See updated answer.

Comment: Click on the Search Settings link in my answer.

Comment: Yes did that alas still no joy....

Comment: You're not being re-directed to the Google France by any chance?

Comment: No checked that and to be sure it is not....

Comment: Go here: chrome://settings/searchEngines and check which search engine(s) Chrome is using.

Comment: Search engine is set to Google.ie

Comment: Still no joy.... beginning to scratch head in wonder...

Comment: You could try deleting all cache and cookie data if you haven't already. Other than that, an uninstall/reinstall may help.

Comment: Yes I shall try this... Thanks for the help Yass

Comment: No probs. I hope you get to the bottom of the problem

Comment: That sorted it....

Comment: Nice to hear :). I'll update my answer. Just to clarify, you mean clearing your browser cache and cookie data?

Comment: Yes, it is the key - Adding and selecting English without adding and selecting any specific English variant (e.g. English - US, English - UK), the menu language does not change. I met similar problem but did not solve it even after googling from other web sites until found this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was with restarting chrome. For activating the language change you need to restart chrome, however a simple right click + restart does not kill the chrome background tasks so the change was not obtained. After killing every chrome process manually it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change language preferences on the operating system. Windows: control panel->languages. Change in all tabs: format, location etc.

restart chrome.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Click **Advanced**
3. Under **Reset and clean up**, click **Reset**
4. Click **Reset**

Answer (score -1):

Nothing has worked for me so far.

Google are more focused on tracking me and my location and are completely overriding my settings.

I can understand why they track users but the settings should be the priority for browser setup. 
People do travel and spend time in other countries and that doesn't mean they want websites to display in those languages.

Comment: Consider describing what you have done to change these settings, and why you think your settings are not being respected.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This isn't an answer to the question, so it is likely to be deleted. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you can track any new answers on your user profile page.

Answer (score -1):

1. Clear all your data from chrome (reset). 
   That'll log you out of everything, and erase your saved passwords, etc.
2. When you open Chrome next time, turn off the sync.

Comment: Please describe ***how*** to do these things.